# Regex to match only commas not in parentheses or square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the string by commas that are not in parentheses or square brackets

I'm working with the following string

> Potatoes, Vegetable Oil (Sunflower, Corn, And/or Canola Oil), Honey
>   BBQ Seasoning [Sugar, Salt, Dextrose, Torula Yeast, Onion Powder,
>   Spices], Maltodextrin Fructose, Yeast Extract, Molasses, Natural Flavor
>   [Including Milk], Corn Starch, Honey, Gum Arabic, Paprika Extracts,
>   Caramel Color, Garlic Powder, Citric Acid, And Sunflower Oil

How i want it split(`+` signifies where i want the split to occur)

> Potatoes+ Vegetable Oil (Sunflower, Corn, And/or Canola Oil)+ Honey BBQ Seasoning [Sugar, Salt, Dextrose, Torula Yeast, Onion Powder, Spices]+ Maltodextrin Fructose+ Yeast Extract+ Molasses+ Natural Flavor [Including Milk]+ Corn Starch+ Honey+ Gum Arabic+ Paprika Extracts+ Caramel Color+ Garlic Powder+ Citric Acid+ And Sunflower Oil

The closest thing i have to working is this

```
,(?![^\[\(]*[$\]\)])
```

https://regex101.com/r/SVSrV2/1

Comment: Where is the matching bracket for `Honey BBQ seasoning [Sugar` and the matching parenthesis for `And Sunflower Oil)`? Does it have to be robust on such malformed input?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the Expression you're using now. All you need to do is ensure that your string contains proper bracket pairs (a **closing** for every **opening**) for both Parentheses and Square Brakets

Comment: ...Still don't see the closing square bracket?

Comment: Yes you understood my question correctly. Sure you can edit it

Comment: Can you give me a hint where the actual list of sub-ingredients of the "BBQ Seasoning" thing actually ends?^^

Comment: It ends after "Natural Flavor [Including Milk]" Sorry its so messed up, thats how i get it from usda

Comment: @SPatrickApps Ahh... The closing bracket is merged with the `[Including Milk]` part... That's of course a pity. But the regex should still work. I've inserted a bracket into your question anyway, it's maybe not correct from culinary point of view, but it makes it easier to understand the question for people who might want to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
(?!<(?:\(|\[)[^)\]]+),(?![^(\[]+(?:\)|\]))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2vqHzD/2)

When fed to Java with the input (note additional `]` and `(` inserted at random positions to make it well-formed):

> Potatoes, Vegetable Oil (Sunflower, Corn, And/or Canola Oil), Honey BBQ Seasoning [Sugar, Salt, Dextrose, Torula Yeast], Onion Powder, Spices, Maltodextrin Fructose, Yeast Extract, Molasses, Natural Flavor [Including Milk], Corn Starch, Honey, Gum Arabic, Paprika Extracts, Caramel Color (Garlic Powder, Citric Acid, And Sunflower Oil).

it produces the output:

```
Potatoes
 Vegetable Oil (Sunflower, Corn, And/or Canola Oil)
 Honey BBQ Seasoning [Sugar, Salt, Dextrose, Torula Yeast]
 Onion Powder
 Spices
 Maltodextrin Fructose
 Yeast Extract
 Molasses
 Natural Flavor [Including Milk]
 Corn Starch
 Honey
 Gum Arabic
 Paprika Extracts
 Caramel Color (Garlic Powder, Citric Acid, And Sunflower Oil).
```

which is exactly the "split at top-level commas".

However, note that this regex is really inefficient. Counting parentheses with regex-lookarounds is not a very good idea. It seems as if it could be solved with a simple scan-left followed by simple split.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you're better off searching for what you want (ie, white-listing), instead of trying to find the split points between the stuff you want (ie, black-listing):

```
String haystack = "Potatoes, Vegetable Oil (Sunflower, Corn, And/or Canola Oil), "
    + "Honey BBQ Seasoning [Sugar, Salt, Dextrose, Torula Yeast], Onion Powder, "
    + "Spices, Maltodextrin Fructose, Yeast Extract, Molasses, "
    + "Natural Flavor [Including Milk], Corn Starch, Honey, Gum Arabic, "
    + "Paprika Extracts, Caramel Color (Garlic Powder, Citric Acid, And Sunflower Oil).";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w[^\\[(,]*(\\[[^]]*\\]|\\([^)]*\\))?")
                   .matcher(haystack);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("'" + m.group() + "'");
}
```

Output:

```
'Potatoes'
'Vegetable Oil (Sunflower, Corn, And/or Canola Oil)'
'Honey BBQ Seasoning [Sugar, Salt, Dextrose, Torula Yeast]'
'Onion Powder'
'Spices'
'Maltodextrin Fructose'
'Yeast Extract'
'Molasses'
'Natural Flavor [Including Milk]'
'Corn Starch'
'Honey'
'Gum Arabic'
'Paprika Extracts'
'Caramel Color (Garlic Powder, Citric Acid, And Sunflower Oil)'
```

Notice that the resulting strings don't include any leading or trailing spaces.

Regex explanation:

`"\w[^\[(,]*(\[[^]]+\]|\([^)]*\))?"` - after backslash escape processing.
`"\w                              "` - find a letter.
`"  [^\[(,]*                      "` - ... followed by anything except a `[` `(` or `,`
`"          (         |         )?"` - ... optionally followed by either:
`"           \[     \]            "` - ...... something in brackets
`"             [^]]*              "` - ......... anything but a `]`
`"                     \(     \)  "` - ...... or something in parentheses
`"                       [^)]*    "` - ......... anything but a `)`