# perl regex to get comma not in parenthesis or nested parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I have a comma separated string and I want to match every comma that is not in parenthesis (parenthesis are guaranteed to be balanced).

```
a   ,   (b)  ,   (d$_,c)    ,     ((,),d,(,))
```

The commas between a and (b),  (b) and (d$*,c), (d$*,c) and ((,),d,(,)) should match but not inside (d$_,c) or ((,),d,(,)).

Note: Eventually I want to split the string by these commas.

It tried this regex:
`(?!<(?:\(|\[)[^)\]]+),(?![^(\[]+(?:\)|\]))` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020531/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses-or-square-brackets#answer-49020667) but it only works for non-nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single regex for this is massively overcomplicated and difficult to maintain or extend. Here is an iterative parser approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'a   ,   (b)  ,   (d$_,c)    ,     ((,),d,(,))';

my $nesting = 0;
my $buffer = '';
my @vals;
while ($str =~ m/\G([,()]|[^,()]+)/g) {
  my $token = $1;
  if ($token eq ',' and !$nesting) {
    push @vals, $buffer;
    $buffer = '';
  } else {
    $buffer .= $token;
    if ($token eq '(') {
      $nesting++;
    } elsif ($token eq ')') {
      $nesting--;
    }
  }
}
push @vals, $buffer if length $buffer;

print "$_\n" for @vals;
```

You can use [Parser::MGC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC) to construct this sort of parser more abstractly.

Comment: The other answer gives a solution. For my project, I use a parser library that does all the heavy work. I am using this regex simply for pretty printing by know what arguments need to be substituted since the parser library doesn't expose this API. Maintaining it isn't a priority because I won't be going any deeper than that.

Comment: Changed to this answer. Other answer had an issue with splitting.  [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678995/why-does-this-regex-fail-to-split-the-string-properly?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|,
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Di2fse/1)

**Details**

- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Capturing group 1: matches a substring between balanced parentheses:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 1 pattern (due to the [regex subroutine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) `(?1)` that is necessary here since only a part of the whole regex pattern is recursed)
  - `\)` - a `)` char.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omits the found match and starts the next search from the end of the match
- `|` - or
- `,` - matches a comma outside nested parentheses.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Perfect!